# parse_str not working as it should?

Tags: php, parsing, url, character

I have a very weird problem with an application I'm developing, what the app does, is take the data from another site and displays it nicely to the user, the data is located here (this is my profile):

http://fairview.deadfrontier.com/onlinezombiemmo/get_values.php?userID=2667244

As you can see, that page looks like a huge query string. The problem is just with one variable, "newpms" (located almost at the end).

This is my code to get all the variables and their values, I'm using parse_str():

```
$url = "http://fairview.deadfrontier.com/onlinezombiemmo/get_values.php?userID=2667244";
$sc = file_get_contents($url);
$str = parse_str(trim($sc));

// wrong value
print $newpms.PHP_EOL;

// examples that show the correct value
print $account_name.PHP_EOL;
print $df_buyer.PHP_EOL;
```

Even if the site shows that the variable newpms is more than 0 on my side it ALWAYS shows as 0, it doesn't matter what value it has. I don't really understand this behavior.

Even if I use is like this, it doesn't work:

```
$url = "http://fairview.deadfrontier.com/onlinezombiemmo/get_values.php?userID=2667244";
$sc = file_get_contents($url);
$data = array();
$str = parse_str(trim($sc), $data);

print_r($data);
```

This would produce (showing only newpms):

> [newpms] => 0

Maybe file_get_contents is retrieving the wrong content?

Thanks

Comment: If you look close into the content of this page, you will realize "newpms" actually *is* set to `0`

Comment: I would post a screenshot as a comment (if possible), but in my browser it displays as `...&newpms=0&...` .. possibly the page checks for your IP or session cookie or something??

Comment: Agreed with Kaii, the url you've added show newpms => 3

Comment: if it's showing `newpms=0` in *my* browser and shows `newpms=3` to *you*, this means the value depends on the client (somehow). Just saying. Find out why. Most likely it displays `newpms=0` to your PHP just like it does to my browser. Find out by printing out the raw result via PHP: `echo $sc;`. I'm 99% positive you will see `newpms=0` there.

Comment: Kaii, I think you're right and I never thought that myself, it seems that page is indeed checking my cookies or something, I opened a new browser with that page and it shows newpms=0.

Comment: Yeah I did that and it always shows newpms=0, well I guess I need to talk to the devs of that game to make that variable open to everyone,thanks for the help :)